# IFrame adjust according to "height" "width" of the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I want Iframe to adjust according to the screen resolution. 
Some auto functionality where i don't need to define height and width manually.

Here is a simple example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/AgRph1fVM1QILkolVEIE?p=preview

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" height="200" width="200">
```

Please Advice..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make an iframe 100% height of a containing div in Firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816703/how-do-i-make-an-iframe-100-height-of-a-containing-div-in-firefox)

Answer (score 1):

You can add an inline style like this.

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height: 100%">
```

Comment: That caused a problem where the outer scroll bar is fixed whereas the inner scrollbar is used to scroll through table.

Comment: add an inline style to the body tag. Like this: '<body style="margin:0px; overflow:hidden"'